# Google Tag Manager how to debug gtm.linkClick

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-tag-manager

My Google Tag Manager set up correctly because other tags are fire a hit.
But, one link click does not fire a hit because **Trigger** is not properly set.

Tricky Part is... **Trigger has a lot of condition**. So I want to know exactly what condition does not match.

I try to look Preview Debug Console result for a link click event...

But I couldn't... because when I click a link, Browser reload Preview Debug Console to initial state and erase link click history from Console.

How can I stop Preview Debug Console from refreshing and look into **gtm.linkClick**?

[image: Debug Console History]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hold down *ctrl* (on Windows) or *cmd* (on Mac) and then click on the link, the link should open up in a new tab and the event should still be visible in the debug window.

If this doesn't work you can download the chrome extension [GTM Sonar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtm-sonar/iiihoahkpncaheicjfemhjkkfamcahcd) with this extension you can "pause" link clicks or form submits.